# How can I set a List of objects as another class property without Entity Framework throwing error?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have these 2 classes:

```
namespace backend.Models
{
    [Table("Orders")]
    public class Order
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public List<OrderItem> items { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And

```
namespace backend.Models
{   
    
    public class OrderItem
    {
        [Required]
        public long ProductId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public long Quantity { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I'm using EF to create a database that will include the "Orders" table. In this table, there will be a field (items) keeping a list of every item that that Order has associated, such as this:

```
[
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "productId": 1,
                "quantity": 1
            },
            {
                "productId": 2,
                "quantity": 1
            }
        ],
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "productId": 2,
                "quantity": 5
            }
        ],
        "id": 2
    }
]
```

Thing is, when I run the "dotnet ef migrations add CreateInitialMigration" command, I get this error:

```
The entity type 'List<string>' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended 
to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more 
information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.
```

I don't know why it reffers to it as a `List<string>` when it's a `List<OrderItem>` though.
I think EF is trying to create a table with the OrderItem class, but I don't want that since this class will only be used to fetch data and store it in the Orders table.

Any help will be appreciated ^^

Comment: For a class called OrderItem, EFC would conventionally expect a property called `Id` or `OrderItemId` as the PK. If you're going to name things outside of what it expects by convention, you'll have to specifically tell it how the entity model is set up. It might be easier just to be conventional

Comment: I think it would be worthwhile to spend some time learning how relations work in entity framework. Entity Framework in this instance (and rightly so) is presuming you have an OrderItem table as well. If you don't want this I think you can use the [IgnoreMapping] attribute but then I doubt you'd get the behaviour that you want.